Google Colab: Unespected Error on Real-Esrgan
just opened Real-ESRGAN Inference Demo (anime video) on Google Colab after some months and I got this when start inference:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/content/Real-ESRGAN/inference_realesrgan_video.py", line 10, in
from basicsr.archs.rrdbnet_arch import RRDBNet
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/basicsr/init.py", line 4, in
from .data import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/basicsr/data/init.py", line 22, in
_dataset_modules = [importlib.import_module(f'basicsr.data.{file_name}') for file_name in dataset_filenames]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/basicsr/data/init.py", line 22, in
_dataset_modules = [importlib.import_module(f'basicsr.data.{file_name}') for file_name in dataset_filenames]
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/basicsr/data/realesrgan_dataset.py", line 11, in
from basicsr.data.degradations import circular_lowpass_kernel, random_mixed_kernels
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/basicsr/data/degradations.py", line 8, in
from torchvision.transforms.functional_tensor import rgb_to_grayscale
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision.transforms.functional_tensor'

I found this on github:
Update degradations.py #624 :
"Fix #533 functional_tensor not found
The torchvision.transforms.functional_tensor module is deprecated since torchvision 0.15, and it will be no longer available in 0.17
Change import source of rgb_to_grayscale from torchvision.transforms.functional_tensor to torchvision.transforms.functional, so as to avoid the deprecation warning."
Since I'm using Real Esrgan on Colab I can't find "degradation.py" so I don't know how to solve this problem (assuming that this will solve the problem).

have you tried with torchvision==0.14 ?

Try this:
!pip uninstall torch torchvision -y
!pip install torch==1.13.0 torchvision==0.14.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/torch_stable.html


There's a thread discussing this issue in the Automatic1111 Github. The  commenters there solve the issue by modifying the import statement in the relevant file in the bacicrs directory within the installed site-packages.  That works, but it's not the easiest.
Thankfully, there's an easier solution now, since the issue was solved in basicsr a month ago (commit 8d56e3a045f9fb3e1d8872f92ee4a4f07f886b0a )
As of this writing, the fix hasn't made it's way into a version that's available on pip yet, but you can install the packaged directly from from Github commit:
pip install git+https://github.com/XPixelGroup/BasicSR@8d56e3a045f9fb3e1d8872f92ee4a4f07f886b0a

Or in a requirements.txt file:
basicsr @ git+https://github.com/XPixelGroup/BasicSR@8d56e3a045f9fb3e1d8872f92ee4a4f07f886b0a

